# Gradle sub-flavours in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to add sub-flavours in gradle?

For example, something like:

```
productFlavors {

    production {

        whitelable1 {
          packageName 'com.bla.whitelable1'
        }

        whitelable2 {
          packageName 'com.bla.whitelable2'
        }

    }

    staging {
        whitelable1 {
          packageName 'com.bla.whitelable1.staging'
        }

        whitelable2 {
          packageName 'com.bla.whitelable2.staging'
        }
    }

}
```